# LRU simulation logical isusses in python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, simulation, lru

I was trying to make [LRU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Least_Recently_Used) paging algorithm usage simulation in python. As argument from bash we take 2 parameters , number of frames and pages. I believe that implementation is ok and program is working, but there are problems with writing out the results. I'm not so fluent in python so maybe I've done something wrong or there is something that I'm missing ?
There is no syntax error, this is logical one so if someone could help me out here it would be big for me.
Help.PLS.

However here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  os5_lru.py
#  


import sys
import string
import random
import numpy as np
from time import sleep

class p_okvira_zastavica:
    def __init__(self):
        O = 0
        Z = 0
#HEADER
def header():
    print '#N\t',
    for i in range (0,okviri):
        print i+1,
        print '\t',
    print 
    print '----------' * okviri
    return 0

#ISPIS
def ispisi(polje_okvira_zastavica,zahtjev,pogodak):
    print "  ", #prints #N
    print zahtjev, 
    print "  ",

    for k in range (0,okviri+1):
        if(polje_okvira_zastavica[k].O == zahtjev):
            if(pogodak):
                if 0 :
                    print "[", #current inserting element
                    print polje_okvira_zastavica[k].O,
                    print "]",
                    break
                if 1:
                    print "(", #if hits
                    print polje_okvira_zastavica[k].O,
                    print ")",
                    break
        else :
            print "  ",
            if polje_okvira_zastavica[k].O!=0 : print polje_okvira_zastavica[k].O ,
            else: print "-",
            print "  ",
    if pogodak == 1:
        print "#Pogodak ",
    print 



#popunjavamo i sve  
def add_vrijednosti(polje_okvira_zastavica,zahtjevi,pokazivac):
    for k in range (0,okviri+1):
        if( zahtjevi == polje_okvira_zastavica[k].O ):
            polje_okvira_zastavica[k].Z = 1
            ispisi(polje_okvira_zastavica,zahtjevi,1)
            return

    while(True):
        if polje_okvira_zastavica[pokazivac].Z == 1:
            polje_okvira_zastavica[pokazivac].Z=0
            pokazivac = (pokazivac+1)%okviri

        else : 
            polje_okvira_zastavica[pokazivac].O = zahtjevi
            polje_okvira_zastavica[pokazivac].Z = 1
            ispisi(polje_okvira_zastavica,zahtjevi,0)
            break
#MAIN   
def main():
    global pokazivac
    pokazivac = 0

    global ulaz,okviri,stranice

    ulaz = list(sys.argv)
    okviri = int(ulaz[1])
    stranice = int(ulaz[2])

    if (okviri < 4 or okviri > 10 ) : print "Error ! Neodgovarajuci broj okvira  "; exit(1)
    if (stranice < 10 or stranice > 100 ) : print "Error ! Neodgovarajuci broj stranica"; exit(1)

    global zahtjevi
    zahtjevi = []


    for i in range (0,stranice):
        zahtjevi.append(random.randint(1,8))
    random.shuffle(zahtjevi)

    print
    print "Zahtjevi :",
    for i in range (0,stranice):
        print zahtjevi[i],
        if (i==stranice-1): break
        print ",",

    print   
    global vrijednosti  
    vrijednosti= [[0 for x in range(okviri+1)] for x in range(stranice)] 
    print       
    polje_okvira_zastavica = [p_okvira_zastavica() for k in range (0,okviri+1)] #array of structures

    for k in range (0,okviri+1):
        polje_okvira_zastavica[k].O = 0
        polje_okvira_zastavica[k].Z = 0

    print "\n\n  #N",
    for k in range (0,okviri):
        print "\t  ",
        print k+1 ,
    print
    print "----------" * okviri 


    pom = stranice
    k = 0
    while(pom!=0):  

        add_vrijednosti(polje_okvira_zastavica,zahtjevi[k],pokazivac)
        k+=1
        pom-=1  

    return 0

#main program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How it should print out results!
[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BvnJ.png)

This is how now prints : 
[image: how now prints]